# modify symbol/stroke of digitized line used during digitizing?

Tags: qgis, symbology, digitizing

I need to digitize line features over a scanned image.  (using Qgis 3.26)

The line during the drawing of the new feature is barely visible: a very thin full red line on completed segment, thin dotted red line for the new/next segment

[image]

Where can I modify this?
So the symbol/stroke used for the current line being digitized.
Not the representation of a finished feature.

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options --> Digitizing --> Rubberband

[image]

Comment: thank you, that's the setting I need.